# Core.vararg issue, garbage produced on repeat calls of va_arg

Tags: d, variadic-functions, void-pointers

Please see the following code:

```
import core.vararg, std.stdio;

void main() {
    foo(1);
}

void foo(...) {
    va_list arguments;
    for(int i; i<10; ++i) {
        va_copy(arguments, _argptr);
        writeln(arguments," ", va_arg!(int)(arguments));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7FFF61F21AE0 1
7FFF61F21AE0 0
7FFF61F21AE0 4387892
7FFF61F21AE0 0
7FFF61F21AE0 38
7FFF61F21AE0 1643256688
7FFF61F21AE0 4387915
7FFF61F21AE0 1
7FFF61F21AE0 27734032
7FFF61F21AE0 1005847240
```

As you can see, var_arg is producing garbage. The first call always returns the correct value however.

What's wrong here? The source code for core.vararg is very simple and I couldn't spot anything that changes the underlying data at 7FFF61F21AE0

Answer (score 2):

`7FFF61F21AE0` looks like a 64-bit address. Note that `core.vararg` forwards its implementation to `core.stdc.stdarg` for platforms other than X86.

The 64-bit implementation is here: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/core/stdc/stdarg.d#L84

The obvious explanation for the code in the example would be that the module is used incorrectly (no `va_start` call), I think.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't believe that any call to va_start is needed to use core.vararg (there aren't any in the examples here: http://dlang.org/function.html). However, there is for core.stdc.stdarg so that must be what's happening to me

Comment: No, whatever i do, whether compiled using x86 or x86_64 and using either syntax, the pointer stays on the same address but va_arg reads the arguments sequentially and then moves on into garbage, despite va_copy being used.